# No GRUB "unlisted ISO" option in YUMI 0.0.1.6 for UEFI?

Tags: linux, iso, boot-loader

On the old YUMI tool for Legacy systems, there was a distribution option of "unlisted ISO" for using the iso rescue disk image from TrueCrypt.  On YUMI 0.0.1.6 (UEFI), there is nothing like that in the drop down list of options. It's all just specific distros of linux, or specific tools like DBAN, Clonezilla, etc etc etc. There's no plain unlisted ISO option. What do I select in YUMI 0.0.1.6 to burn the ISO of a Veracrypt rescue disk?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [changelog](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/),

> The following YUMI UEFI version is a work in progress that utilize GRUB2 for both UEFI and BIOS booting. Please NOTE that it is not backwards compatible with standard YUMI. Supported distributions are limited, and your USB drive must be Fat32 formatted to support booting in UEFI mode. (Only BIOS mode will work with NTFS formatted drives).

Note: The option is still present under YUMI-2.0.6.6, (05/28/2019).

**EDIT**

For a deeper, more technical answer; support for unlisted ISOs has been removed.

To verify this, download the sources for YUMI UEFI 0.0.1.6, then search for Unlisted in the file `InstallDistro.nsh`.

The same file in the YUMI 2.0.6.6 sources contains the following section,

```
; Unlisted ISOs

${ElseIf} $DistroName == "Try Unlisted ISO (GRUB)"

${ElseIf} $DistroName == "Try Unlisted ISO (GRUB from RAM)"

...
```

Note: The contents of the file have been truncated for brevity.

I'd recommend using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie), as it supports BIOS and UEFI.

Comment: This doesn't answer why "unlisted ISO" isn't an option. Using YUMI 2.0 isn't an option either because that program cannot create a bootable ISO that works with the UEFI veracrypt bootloader.

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't understand the "Supported distributions are limited" part. It hasn't been added to the new version yet.

Comment: I'm not sure you can just use Rufus to create a VeraCrypt rescue disk. Where would the special menu.lst file with all the unix code come from?

Comment: but `Rufus` seems not support multiboot ( burn multi iso into one usb stick ) ?